# If $f(x)=o(g(x))$ at $0$ does $\int_0^tf(x)=o\left(\int_0^t g(x)dx\right)$ when $t\to 0$?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f(x)=o(g(x))$ when $x\to 0$. Does $$\int_0^t f(x)dx=o\left(\int_0^t g(x)dx\right)$$ when $t\to 0$ ?

---

For me is true, but my teacher says that my proof is wrong without explanation. Can someone explain where I'm wrong ?

Let $\varepsilon >0$. There is $\delta >0$ s.t. $|f(x)|\leq \varepsilon |g(x)|$ when $|x|\leq \delta $. Let $|t|\leq \delta $, then $$\int_0^t|f(x)|dx\leq \varepsilon \int_0^t|g(x)|dx,$$
and thus $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\int_0^t |f(x)|dx}{\int_0^t |g(x)|dx}\leq \varepsilon ,$$
therefore $$\int_0^t |f(x)|dx=o\left(\int_0^t|g(x)|\right).$$
So if $f,g\geq 0$, then the claim is true.

**Question :** So, I proved the claim for $f,g\geq 0$ only. But from here, isn't it obvious that the claim is true for integrable $f$ and $g$ by writting $f=f^+-f^-$ and $g=g^+-g^-$ (where $f^+(x)=\max(f(x),0)$ and $f^-(x)=-\min(f(x),0)$) ?

Comment: No. Going from the case $f,g \geq 0$ to the general case is not obvious.

Comment: at least, the case $f,g\geq 0$ is correct ? If yes, how can you generalize it when $f$ and $g$ no positive ? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: I don't see any simple way of going from positive to general case, so your approach does not work.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Maybe it's wrong in general ? (if $f$ and $g$ are not continuous)

Comment: You can find $g$ such that $\int_0^{1/n} g(x)dx=0$ for every $n$ but there is a positive function $f$ with $f=o(g)$. In this case the conclusion fails.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming  that $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions and $\int_0^{t} g(x)dx$ does not vanish for $|t|$ sufficiently small  you get this result immediately from L'Hopital's Rule.